# How to start 2 (or more) processes in parallel from a function

Tags: python, multiprocessing

im trying to start 2 processes in parallel from a function in a class, but it is not working. I am trying something like that:

```
 from multiprocessing import Process

 class MyClass():

     #something here to create a large list L

     def myClassFunction1():
        #something here
        ....
        ....
     def myClassFunction2():
        #something here
        p1 = Process(target=myProcess1,args=(L,))
        p2 = Process(target=myProcess2,args=(L,))
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        p1.join()
        p2.join()
        #something else here

    def myProcess1(L):
        #do something here with L

    def myProcess2(L):
        #do something here with L
```

I am not very good in python.....and I don't get to understand very good how the multiprocessing works. I hope someone can give me some help.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you've got a type on your code, shouldn't it be p1.start() and p2.start() ...? The same applies for the joins.

Comment: yes I just noticed, edited

Comment: Does this throw an error?

Comment: yeah, I get an error, in this prticular case will be like that:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'myProcess1' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the functions as an instance method:

```
p1 = Process(target=self.myProcess1,args=(L,))
p2 = Process(target=self.myProcess2,args=(L,))
```

And in your worker functions, add self as the first argument:

```
def myProcess1(self, L):
    #do something awesome with L
def myProcess1(self, L):
    #do something as awesome as myProcess1 with L
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: myProcess2 will need to take self as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

I've never used multiprocessing module before, but you could use threading module...

```
import threading

class worker (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,extraArgs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.storeArgs = extraArgs
    def run(self):
        //add code can use self.storeArgs


a = worker(argsA)
b = worker(argsB)
a.start()  //starts concurrent thread using worker.run()
b.start()  //starts concurrent thread using worker.run()

while threading.activeCount()>1:  //loop to make sure threads are finished running
    continue
```

You can either make two classes for the different methods you want to run or give the worker two methods and use if/else or case logic to decide which one to use in it's run/start method

Comment: yeah I think I could use threading as well but, as far as I know (tell me if im wrong), with threading you are not using REAL multiprocessing, I mean, with threading you are not "keeping busy" more than one processor in your system...Am I right??

Answer (score 0):

Just define the functions before create the process. Python interpreter read the module line by line, by the time it reaches the lines creating the processes, that functions aren't defined.

I recommend you put those functions in a separated module and then import from there.